# Flutter - Agora remote video not shown on Android

Tags: android, flutter, agora.io, videocall

Remote video always shown as white screen and cannot see the remote video even though the event listener was working (i.e. can see which user joined). I am using the latest version of agora_rtc_engine: ^6.0.0. It works if i just use the agora ui kit. Here is the code to get the remote video from agora_rtc_engine.

```
AgoraVideoView(
    controller: VideoViewController.remote(
    rtcEngine: _engine,
    canvas: VideoCanvas(uid: 'user-id'),
    connection: const RtcConnection(channelId: 'channelName')
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kean I am having the same issue did you get anywhere?

Comment: Could you try generating a new appId in the Agora Console? I had a similar issue and that seemed to fix it

Comment: @IsisCuriel Yup I did not enable video (i.e. call enableVideo()) in my code.

Comment: @TadasPetra Thanks for the reply. I managed to resolve it. :)

Answer (score -1):

you have to make set

```
sourceType:VideoSourceType.videoSourceRemote,


AgoraVideoView(controller: VideoViewController.remote(
                                  rtcEngine: controller.engine!,
                                  canvas: VideoCanvas(
                                    uid: uid,
                                    sourceType:
                                        VideoSourceType.videoSourceRemote,
                                  ),
                                  connection: const RtcConnection(
                                    channelId: 'channelId',
                                  ),
                                ),
```